# Is there a hotel aggregation site that can sort by TripAdvisor rating?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

Is there a hotel aggregation site that can sort by TripAdvisor rating?

I find TripAdvisor lacks the filtering options available on most aggregation sites, but hotel aggregation sites generally lack the same massive user base that TripAdvisor boasts so has a fraction of the reviews and less "wisdom of the crowd".  I'd like to be able to combine the two when it comes to searching for hotels.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.alltherooms.com.  It's a hotel meta-search engine that includes links to TripAdvisor profiles.